# Actualizar version PHP en MAC

Tags: php, macos, terminal, actualizacion, homebrew

Cuando ejecuto brew install php el error que me sale es: 
**Error: php: Failed to download resource "freetds"**
**Download failed: Homebrew-installed `curl` is not installed for: https://www.freetds.org/files/stable/freetds-1.3.6.tar.gz** 
Me sale en las versiones de php el 8.0 pero cuando lo linkeo me sale el error: 
**no such keg /usr/local/cellar/php**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780980/cant-install-php7-or-php-7-1-with-homebrew

Comment: Ejecuté esos comandos pero no me solucionó nada.